# Would you tell me more about "however" vs. "still" vs. "nevertheless"

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

In this example, is there any difference between these two words? Which one should be used, and why?

> I enjoyed the trip very much; **however**, my roommate did not.
> I enjoyed the trip very much; **still**, my roommate did not.
>
> I had planned to drive to Mexico; **however**, my car is too old.
> I had planned to drive to Mexico; **nevertheless**, my car is too old.

And can I move one of these words to the beginning of the sentence?

> **However**, my car is too old; I had planned to drive to Mexico.
> I had planned to drive to Mexico; **however**, my car is too old.

So, considering what have been said, would anybody tell me which one and why?

Comment: Which do you think is right, and why? Why did you choose these words as options? Tell us a little more about what you're thinking, please, so we can tailor our answers to the source of the confusion.

Comment: I have found the at the followings: The book [_Communicate What You Mean_](http://www.amazon.com/Communicate-What-You-Mean-Advanced/dp/0135201071), plus Dictionaries. I am now so confused that I cannot even think how to explain any further

Comment: A dictionary gave you one of the above sentences, with a choice between *however* and *nevertheless*? Can you tell us which dictionary so we can look it up ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I enjoyed the trip very much; however, my roommate did not. - YES
>
> I enjoyed the trip very much; still, my roommate did not. - NO
>
> I had planned to drive to Mexico; however, my car is too old. - YES
>
> I had planned to drive to Mexico; nevertheless, my car is too old. - NO
>
> However, my car is too old; I had planned to drive to Mexico. - NO

Still/Nevertheless always indicates some sort of surprise. However can indicate either surprise or be used simply for contrast. Consider:

> Jane lived in Tokyo for ten years; nevertheless, she can't speak any Japanese. - YES (SURPRISE)
>
> Jane lived in Tokyo for ten years; however, she can't speak any Japanese. - YES (SURPRISE)
>
> Hiro lives in Japan. His girlfriend, nevertheless, lives in Taiwan. - NO (NEED CONTRAST, ONLY GIVES SURPRISE)
>
> Hiro lives in Japan. His girlfriend, however, lives in Taiwan. - YES (CONTRAST)

You can find more information at http://www.connect2esl.com/main/activities/however_nevertheless1.htm.

Answer (score 4):

*However* introduces a simple contradictory statement and can usually be substituted with **but**:

> The blue ones taste good, however [*but*] the red ones do not.

*Still* introduces a contradictory statement in the face of contrary evidence and can usually be substituted with **even so**:

> The same company makes the blue ones and the red ones from the same recipe, still, I don't like the red ones.

Note that in many cases one word can be exchanged for another in a sentence, but the resulting sentence may convey a slightly different meaning.

> The blue ones taste good, still, the red ones do not.

This now means, that even though the blue ones taste good the red ones don't;

Still is often used when you are disagreeing with someone who has presented an argument for their position.  You are essentially saying, Even given your arguments I *still* don't agree with you.

> "You should come to the party.  Joe will be there."
>   "Still," [*you are considering the fact that Joe will be there*] "I don't think I'll be going." [ *You have decided against attending even though Joe will be there.*]

In your example using *however*:

> I enjoyed the trip, however my roommate did not.

you are simply stating two facts:  you liked it,  your roommate did not.

If you use *still*:

> I enjoyed the trip, still, my roommate did not.

you are now saying, even though I liked it, my roommate did not.

You are now saying that your liking the trip could have had an influence on whether your roommate liked it too, but it didn't.